# Is it possible to change the way a list of algorithms is generated to include the word "Algorithm" before each element in the list?

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

I've tried using both `algorithm2e` and `algorithmic` to generate a list of algorithms, but they both do it this way:

```
List of Algorithms

1 BFS ..... 1
2 DFS ..... 2
...
```

When I'd like to it to be:

```
List of Algorithms

Algorithm 1 BFS ..... 1
Algorithm 2 DFS ..... 2
...
```

The packages being used:

```
\documentclass[pnumabnt,normaltoc,capchap,floatnumber=continuous]{abnt}  
\usepackage[bibjustif,abnt-etal-cite=2,abnt-full-initials=yes]{abntcite}
\usepackage[toc,page]{modelo/tex/appendix}
\usepackage[portuguese,brazilian,portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{abnt-alf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[portugues]{algorithm2e}
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it obvious, that below the heading **List of Algorithms** only algorithms follow? Why mention 20 times *Algorithm* again?

One could start by redefining the counter presentation like

```
\renewcommand*{\thealgocf}{Algorithm~\arabic{algocf}}
```

But the list of contents requires modification, this could be done with a package like `tocloft` or `titletoc` or `tocbasic`.

For consistency it may be following to do the same for figures, tables, sections and so on. That seems odd to me.

Comment: i want algorithm for every instance for consistency with the list of tables and figures. they followed a model so i can't help it. also, could you explain better how to fix it? i don't follow, sorry i'm new to latex.

Comment: also, it seems that to use that `\renewcommand` I have to specify the margin/spacing or else "Algorithm" is garbled along the beginning of the Algorithm name. Is there a parameter for that?

Comment: It's unclear which document class and which packages (captions, tocloft etc.) you're using. Provide a reduced but compilable example showing what you're actually doing. Especially what you mean with following a model and how it's already done with figures and tables. If I would just guess and post an example it would be unclear if it fits to your code.

Comment: well, i can post the packages i'm importing, but i can't post the model here. if that isn't enough for you to answer i understand.

Comment: You could insert dummy algorithm text, figures and tables- fire up the Lorem Ipsum generator.

Answer (score 1):

The construction of the List of Algorithms uses the `\l@algocf` macro (or at least when I use the `algorithm2e` package it does). This may be slightly different depending on your algorithm package/settings/...

Anyway, you could place the following in the preamble in order to change the way that lines in the TOC are drawn:

```
\makeatletter
\let{\oldl@algocf}{\l@algocf}
\renewcommand{\l@algocf}[2]{\oldl@algocf{Algorithm #1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

- The first and last lines simply allow you to use the `@` character in macro names.
- The second line makes a copy of the original `\l@algocf` macro (so you can call it on the 3rd line)
- The third line redefines the `\l@algocf` macro to insert the word Algorithm before the first argument (the caption text) in the TOC line.

Comment: gives me an error :( (! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> \inaccessible l.57 \let{\oldl@algocf}{\l@algocf})

Comment: I think this means your algorithms TOC isn't getting generated with `\l@algocf`. Check the documentation of your algorithms package to see if you can find what its using to generate the TOC lines (it'll almost definitely be a macro starting with `\l@` and ending with `cf`). In some packages, the name of that function is generated from the naming of your algorithm environment (e.g. you might define the "algo" or "algorithm" environment so as to be different from "theories" "examples" "lemmas" etc... in which case the documentation should specify how it generates that macro name)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this problem correctly.

First, the solution proposed by [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1414) doesn't solve the problem in `algorithm2e` package, cause the command \thealgocf although is used to represent the numeration in list of algorithms, it's is also used in titles for algorithm environment. Also the new name is cropped with the number as reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/is-it-possible-to-change-the-way-a-list-of-algorithms-is-generated-to-include-th#comment1882_1414).

So backing to [drfrogslap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1799) answer, the idea was right, just \let expression was wrong. So to fix this and solve the problem just use the follow code:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldl@algocf\l@algocf
\renewcommand{\l@algocf}[2]{\oldl@algocf{Algorithm #1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Thanks drfrogslap for the answer.