# Add algorithm label to list of algorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, classicthesis

I'm using the `classicthesis` package along with the `algorithmic` package.

I'm trying to get the list of algorithms to look the same as the list of figures/tables etc., but cant find a way to make it appear as:

```
Algorithm 1.1        First Algorithm
Algorithm 1.2        Second Algorithm
Algorithm 1.3        Third Algorithm
```

Instead it appears as:

```
Figure 1.1        First Algorithm
Figure 1.2        Second Algorithm
Figure 1.3        Third Algorithm
```

Any ideas?

**edit #1:** I've tried the following from this [suggested post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/is-it-possible-to-change-the-way-a-list-of-algorithms-is-generated-to-include-th)

```
\makeatletter
\let{\oldl@algocf}{\l@algocf}
\renewcommand{\l@algocf}[2]{\oldl@algocf{Algorithm #1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

But that gives a number of errors beggining with:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
\inaccessible
l.276 \let{
\oldl@algocf}{\l@algocf}
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
```

I'm using the following algorithm packages:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

One comment on that post suggested replacing `l@algocf` with `l@algorithmcf` but that gives similar errors

**edit #2:** As requested heres a simplified example that produces the listing without the algorithm label, note you need classicthesis.sty and classicthesis-config.tex in the build directory, they can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/downloads/detail?name=classicthesis.v4.1.zip&can=2&q=). A sample pdf produced with this code can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4Y0idbHnikgcmVON19jM21uXzg)

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,%         letterpaper a4paper
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
            BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
            ngerman,american,%
            ]{scrreprt}

\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\numberwithin{algorithm}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

%********************************************************************
% Frontmatter
%*******************************************************
\listofalgorithms

%********************************************************************
% Mainmatter
%*******************************************************
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Test Algorithm}
\label{alg:test}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{$i \gets i + 1$}
\State $a = 2i$
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\cleardoublepage


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Is it possible to change the way a list of algorithms is generated to include the word “Algorithm” before each element in the list?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/is-it-possible-to-change-the-way-a-list-of-algorithms-is-generated-to-include-th).

Comment: Thanks Peter, I've updated my question accordingly. The solution there didn't solve my problem, as I'm not useing the algorithm2e package.

Comment: @BruceJones Could you please add a minimal example of code?

Comment: egreg, I've added an example showing what I'm currently doing.

Comment: @BruceJones Sorry, but the example does not compile. What `classicthesis-config.tex` file are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I've added a link to a zip file which includes the two required files. I hadnt realised there was a new version of classicthesis, now the list of algorithms entries are preceeded by "Figure"... though i cant find any reference to an algorithm package in the two files. Note, for this to compile with the new example remove the \setlanguage{british} line, it has been removed in example provided here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try with

```
\listofalgorithms
\addtocontents{loa}{\def\string\figurename{Algorithm}}
```

How `classicthesis` manages added lists is not completely without problems.

Comment: Thanks egreg, works perfectly. Also thanks for prompting me to look at the newer version of classicthesis, it has sorted out a spacing problem I had with the list of algorithms beforehand.