# Add the word "Algorithm" before each entry in the List of Algorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms

I'm trying to add the word "Algorithm" before each entry in the List of Algorithms (because of unavoidable thesis guidelines).

I saw similar questions but the solutions listed there don't work for me. I'm not sure about reopening those questions, hence posting it separately. Apologize if that's not the right etiquette.

[Is it possible to change the way a list of algorithms is generated to include the word "Algorithm" before each element in the list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/is-it-possible-to-change-the-way-a-list-of-algorithms-is-generated-to-include-th)  (I'm using "algorithm" package instead of "algorithm2e")

[Add algorithm label to list of algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82391/add-algorithm-label-to-list-of-algorithms) (not sure if solutions listed there require other packages as listed solutions don't work for me)

Current output:

```
List of Algorithms
1 Optimization . . . . . . . . 3
```

Desired output:

```
List of Algorithms
Algorithm 1 Optimization . . . . . . . . 3
```

Here's a simplified code sample that illustrates the issue. Your help is much appreciated. Please let me know how to get desired behavior for this sample.

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{book}                                                                                                                                                                             
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\title{Sample book}
\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Sample}
% Outline
\begin{algorithm}[!hbt]
    \centering
    \caption{Optimization}\label{alg:pso}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \STATE \textit{GenerateInitialPopulation}(pop)
        \FOR {particle $ \leftarrow $ 1 \textit{to} numParticles}
          \STATE \textit{Evaluate}(particle)
        \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Thanks for providing a MWE :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following piece of code will insert `Algorithm~` before each number of the algorithm in the List of Algorithms (LoA):

```
\begingroup
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithm~\oldnumberline}
\listofalgorithms
\endgroup
```

It redefines the `\numberline` macro that inserts and sets the algorithm number into the LoA. For a good discussion on the meanings and placement/usage of these macros, read the [`tocloft` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) (section **1.1 LaTeX's methods**). Bracing (or grouping using `\begingroup`...`\endgroup`) localizes the scope so it does not affect `\numberline` used by other contents structures. Here's the full code that redefines `\listofalgorithms` so it can be cleanly used inside your document body:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\let\oldlistofalgorithms\listofalgorithms
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithm~\oldnumberline}%
  \oldlistofalgorithms%
  \endgroup}
\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Sample}
% Outline
\begin{algorithm}[!hbt]
  \centering
  \caption{Optimization}\label{alg:pso}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE \textit{GenerateInitialPopulation}(pop)
    \FOR {particle $ \leftarrow $ 1 \textit{to} numParticles}
      \STATE \textit{Evaluate}(particle)
    \ENDFOR
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to avoid the horizontal space introduced between the margin and the algorithm contents entries, you can use the following redefinition of `\listofalgorithms`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \let\old@dottedtocline\@dottedtocline
  \renewcommand{\@dottedtocline}[5]{\old@dottedtocline{##1}{0pt}{##3}{##4}{##5}}%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithm~\oldnumberline}%
  \oldlistofalgorithms%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

The above update of `\@dottedtocline` changes the default `1.5em` spacing usually placed in the second argument with `0pt`.

[image]

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: This works but leaves horizontal space on the left. No way to override the `\contentsline` directly?

Comment: @theswine: See my updated answer.

Comment: @Werner oh, nice, just slapped `\let\oldlistofalgorithms\listofalgorithms` on top and works like a charm. Thanks a lot (upvoted yesterday already).

Answer (score 0):

Both worked for me:

```
\makeatletter
\let\l@algocf\l@figure
\makeatother
\let\oldfigurename\figurename
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\algorithmcfname}
\listofalgorithms
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\oldfigurename}
```

and

```
\let\oldlistofalgorithms\listofalgorithms
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\newcommand{\algnumberline}[1]{Algorithm~#1 -- }
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{%
  \let\numberline\algnumberline%
  \oldlistofalgorithms
  \let\numberline\oldnumberline%
}
```

The first considers that the table of figures already have the desired formatting.