# "Algorithm" in LOA

Tags: table-of-contents, parts

I want to add the word "Algorithm" in the LOA.
Using this approach: [Algorithm in LOA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96969/add-the-word-algorithm-before-each-entry-in-the-list-of-algorithms)
adds the term to the LOA.
However, because I want to further structure my LOA (acc. to "Parts") I aim at also adding the Part- number as headlines in the TOC/LOF/LOA.
However, using this code also writes "Algorithm" in front of the "Part-number"

The following MWE illustrates the issue:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

% Adding "Algorithm" in LOA

\let\oldlistofalgorithms\listofalgorithms
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithm~\oldnumberline}%
  \oldlistofalgorithms%
  \endgroup}
\begin{document}

% Adding headlines in LOA
\newcommand{\addtocentrylistof}[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{%
   \addcontentsline{lof}{#1}{#3}%
   \addcontentsline{lot}{#1}{#3}%
    \addcontentsline{loa}{#1}{#3}%
  }{%
    \addcontentsline{lof}{#1}{\protect\numberline{#2}#3}%
    \addcontentsline{lot}{#1}{\protect\numberline{#2}#3}%
   \addcontentsline{loa}{#1}{\protect\numberline{#2}#3}%
  }%
}

\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
 \addtocentrydefault{part}{#1}{#2}%
 \addtocentrylistof{part}{#1}{#2}%
}


\listofalgorithms
\part{A}

% Outline
\begin{algorithm}[!hbt]

  \centering
  \caption{Optimization}\label{alg:pso}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE \textit{GenerateInitialPopulation}(pop)
    \FOR {particle $ \leftarrow $ 1 \textit{to} numParticles}
      \STATE \textit{Evaluate}(particle)
    \ENDFOR
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

What I want:
Just the Part-number (here: "I) and then the part-Title (here: "A") as headline above all algorithms that are also called "Algorithm 1..."

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi - thank you for this hint. I've updated the question, including a MWE!

Comment: Guys - anny suggestions? This is quite urgent, as I have to submit mit thesis asap :/

Comment: You added some code, but I can't compile it. No `\documentclass`

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks.I've added the documentclass for the koma-script "report"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve what you're after is to intercept the printing of `\numberline` in `\l@part` - the macro responsible for printing a `\part`-like entry in a ToC-related file:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{algorithm,etoolbox}

% Adding "Algorithm" in LOA

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\partnumberline}[1]{Part~#1\quad\ignorespaces}
\patchcmd{\l@part}% <cmd>
  {\leavevmode}% <search>
  {\leavevmode\let\numberline\partnumberline}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\let\oldlistofalgorithms\listofalgorithms
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
  \renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithm~\oldnumberline}%
  \oldlistofalgorithms%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

% Adding headlines in LOA
\newcommand{\addtocentrylistof}[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}{%
   \addcontentsline{lof}{#1}{#3}%
   \addcontentsline{lot}{#1}{#3}%
    \addcontentsline{loa}{#1}{#3}%
  }{%
    \addcontentsline{lof}{#1}{\protect\numberline{#2}#3}%
    \addcontentsline{lot}{#1}{\protect\numberline{#2}#3}%
   \addcontentsline{loa}{#1}{\protect\numberline{#2}#3}%
  }%
}

\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
 \addtocentrydefault{part}{#1}{#2}%
 \addtocentrylistof{part}{#1}{#2}%
}


\listofalgorithms
\part{A}

% Outline
\begin{algorithm}[!hbt]
  \centering
  \caption{Optimization}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The above patch (thanks to [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) replaces `\numberline` in `\l@part` with `\partnumberline`, and we defined this to just print `Part~#1\quad`.