# List of Algorithm: add "algorithm" label

Tags: algorithms

I want to add label "Algorithm" to the numbering of list of algorithms,
e.g.,

1. Algorithm 1. Search
2. Algorithm 2. Sort

I tried different solutions found here but does not work.

The main .tex file is here:

```
\documentclass[PhD]{msu-thesis}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\title{Contributions to Computer-Aided Diagnosis of Prostate Cancer in Histopathology}
\author{Kien Nguyen}
\date{2013}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitlepage

\include{Chapter_UpdateJune/abstract}

\clearpage

\include{Chapter_UpdateJune/acknowledgement}
\SingleSpacing
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listofalgorithms
%\addtocontents{loa}{\def\string\figurename{Algorithm}}
%\renewcommand*{\thealgocf}{Algorithm~\arabic{algocf}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
\mainmatter
%\include{Chapter_UpdateJune/ch1_intro_v2}
\include{Chapter_UpdateJune/ch2_glandseg_v7}
%\include{Chapter_UpdateJune/ch3_imageclassify}
%\include{Chapter_UpdateJune/ch3_nucleibased_v2}
%\include{Chapter_UpdateJune/ch4_retrieval_v2}
%\include{Chapter_UpdateJune/ch5_cytology_v3}
%\include{Chapter_UpdateJune/ch6_summary}
\backmatter
\makebibliographycover
\SingleSpacing
\bibliography{FullBib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you also post the issue you get when you compile the [MWE from the question you linked to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82391/10102)?

Comment: I either get the same errors when using the previous post or I do not see any label appearing in the List of Algorithms

Comment: Should I edit the file algorithm.sty to achieve this?

Comment: No! Do not modify algorithm.sty! You can always change what the `algorithm` package does in your .tex file, but never change the distribution files themselves.

Comment: `algorithm` is an old package for latex209.  You should try and use a new package, e.g. `algorithm2e`; with that package http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1799/15925 works for me.

Comment: Thanks. You mean this command: \renewcommand*{\thealgocf}{Algorithm~\arabic{algocf}}. Using this, the label "Algorithm" shows as overlapping on the algorithm title. Do you have similar problem?

Comment: I found this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96969/add-the-word-algorithm-before-each-entry-in-the-list-of-algorithms/126595#126595 It works for the "algorithm" package. a great code

Comment: Then I guess we can close this question as a duplicate of that one?

Comment: I actually linked to the other answer, exactly because it avoids the problem of overlapping.